# split not working correctly

Tags: java, split

I am trying to save the groups in a string to an array so that I can use them in individual variables if I need to. For this I use *split* but for some reason I only get the full string in the first position in the array: ultimate_array[0]. If I want to use ultimate_array[1] I get an exception like "out of bounds".
Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
String string_final = "";
String[] ultimate_array = new String[100];
String sNrFact = "";

string_final="Nrfact#$idfact1#$valfact1#$idfact2#$valfact2#$idfact3#$valfact3#$idfact4#$valfact4#$idfact5#$valfact5#$idfact6#$valfact6#$idfact7#$valfact7#$idfact8#$valfact8#$idfact9#$valfact9#$idfact10#$valfact10";

ultimate_array = string_final.split("#$");
sNrFact = ultimate_array[0];
```

Comment: The argument to `split()` should be a regex, so `$` is matching "end of string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `$` (*end of string*)

```
ultimate_array = string_final.split("#\\$");
```

Answer (score 3):

The split takes an regular expression and `$` is a special character (end of string) so you have to escape it with backslash `\`. Anyway it is also special character, this time in Java, so you have to escape it also. The final code is:

```
ultimate_array = string_final.split("#\\$");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ultimate_array = string_final.split("#\\$");
```

The reason your split is not working correctly is that split uses regex and "$" is a special character for regexes(*drekka*)

Comment: 's answer is correct. The reason your split is not working correctly is that split uses regex and "$" is a special character for regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your line:

```
ultimate_array = string_final.split("#$");
```

with:

```
ultimate_array = string_final.Split(new string[] { "#$" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I hope your problem is resolved...